# How to extract only one field from JSON into Google Sheets using Google Sheets app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function import_inventory_test(e) {

var options = {

       "method" : "GET",
       "headers" : {
       'Content-Type' : 'application/json' ,
       'Prefer': 'code=200',
       'Prefer':'dynamic=true',
       "clientId" : "1",
       "key": "1"}}
 

  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/inventory",options).getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);
     

}
```

How can convert one field from the response into an entire column in google sheets?

For example, let's say that there are 100 items in the JSON above and I want to extract only the "sku" for all 100 products and I would like to enter all of those 100 SKU's into the "A" column in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the values of `sku` in column "A" using your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function import_inventory_test(e) {
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Prefer': 'code=200',
      'Prefer': 'dynamic=true',
      "clientId": "1",
      "key": "1",
    }
  }
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/inventory?max=100", options).getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);

  // I added the below script.
  var values = json.data.map(({ sku }) => [sku]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- About `For example, let's say that there are 100 items in the JSON above and I want to extract only the "sku" for all 100 products and I would like to enter all of those 100 SKU's into the "A" column in Google Sheets?`, when I tested your script, 20 items are returned in `json.data`. If you want to retrieve 100 SKU values, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function import_inventory_test(e) {
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Prefer': 'code=200',
        'Prefer': 'dynamic=true',
        "clientId": "1",
        "key": "1",
      }
    }

    // I added the below script.
    var requests = [...Array(5)].map(_ => ({ url: "https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/inventory", ...options }));
    var values = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests).flatMap(r => JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).data.map(({ sku }) => [sku]));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
  }
  ```
- In this modification, the empty values and the duplicated values are included. If you want to remove them, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function import_inventory_test(e) {
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Prefer': 'code=200',
        'Prefer': 'dynamic=true',
        "clientId": "1",
        "key": "1",
      }
    }

    // I added the below script.
    var max = 100;
    var requests = [...Array(6)].map(_ => ({ url: "https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/inventory", ...options }));
    var values = [...new Set(UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests).flatMap(r => JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).data.map(({ sku }) => sku).filter(String)))].splice(0, max).map(e => [e]);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Amazing (as always!) Thank you for the multiple script variation! you are the best! would you mind creating another version? if you prefer I can create a new question

I want to know how to modify your first script to include multiple fields, let's say I want to populate a-d columns with the following fields (by that order): sku (A) quantity (B) productName (C) brand (D)

Comment: @Kal El Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `would you mind creating another version? if you prefer I can create a new question`, when I saw your posted new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74920247/how-to-extract-only-multiple-field-from-json-into-google-sheets-using-google-she