# How to extract only multiple field from JSON into Google Sheets using Google Sheets app script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function import_inventory_test(e) {
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Prefer': 'code=200',
      'Prefer': 'dynamic=true',
      "clientId": "1",
      "key": "1",
    }
  }
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/inventory?max=100", options).getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);

  // I added the below script.
  var values = json.data.map(({ sku }) => [sku]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

How can I populate a-d columns with the following fields (by that order): sku (A) quantity (B) productName (C) brand (D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = json.data.map(({ sku }) => [sku]);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
```

#### To:

```
var values = json.data.map(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand }) => [sku, quantity, productName, brand]);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Note:

- If you want to add and modify the values you need, in this case, please modify `json.data.map(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand }) => [sku, quantity, productName, brand])`.

#### Reference:

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: I wanted to mark your answer as "solved" but I have to wait 10 minutes! you are the man! kudos to you! thank you very very much

Comment: @Kal El Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this modified script, when you want to change the required values, you can simply retrieve it by modifying `json.data.map(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand }) => [sku, quantity, productName, brand]);`.